# Conjugating the curvature with a parallel transport operator does not make sense

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, holonomy

I'm trying to understand the proof of the Ambrose-Singer theorem, following, for instance, [Werner Ballmann's notes](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/hwbllmnn/archiv/conncurv1999.pdf). I understand that the gist of the theorem is that, when you have a vector bundle $(E,\nabla) \to M$, the holonomy algebra $\mathfrak{hol}_x(\nabla)$ is going to be generated by conjugates of curvature operators $R^\nabla(v,w)$, $v,w \in T_xM$, by parallel transport operators $P_\alpha\colon E_x \to E_x$, where $\alpha \in \Omega(M,x)$ is a loop. In more than one place, I have seen the following notation

$$R^\nabla_\alpha (v,w) \doteq P_\alpha \circ R^\nabla({\color{red}{P_\alpha v}},{\color{red}{P_\alpha w}}) \circ P_{\alpha}^{-1}.$$Computing $P_\alpha$ at $v$ and $w$ makes *absolutely no sense* to me. They live in $T_xM$, not in $E_x$! The only thing I can imagine is that since $\nabla$ induces a horizontal distribution on the total space $E$ (namely, one sets $v^{\sf h}_{(x,\phi)} \in E_x$ to be ${\rm d}\psi_x(v)$, where $\psi$ is any local section around $x$ with $(\nabla\psi)_x=0$ and $\psi_x=\phi$), one would mean to apply $P_\alpha$ to horizontal lifts -- and even still -- the matter of the "height" $\phi \in E_x$ remains undecided. Not to say nothing about horizontal lifts is said anywhere. And I don't think you're supposed to arbitrarily pick an auxilliary connection in $TM$ to do it.

What is going on?

Comment: The connection not only fixes a horizontal distribution on $E$ but it also defines a *specific* horizontal lift - actually, the former can defined as the image of the latter.

Comment: Sure. But it's still not clear what $P_\alpha v$ would be here. I'm under the impression that horizontal lifts are not related to this at all, since we can only transport things living in the fibers..

Comment: Thinking better, the problem seems to be that the formula you wrote actually relates to the connection on a *principal* bundle, not on a vector bundle - more precisely, on the frame bundle associated to this vector bundle. The Ambrose-Singer theorem is usually stated for principal bundles.

Comment: In the context of principal bundles, the parallel transport operator is needed so we know over which point of the total space we are computing $R^\nabla$ (or the frame bundle equivalent thereof) and (the horizontal lifts of) $v,w$. In other words, the parallel transport operator is responsible for lifting the base curve $\alpha$ to the total space of the frame bundle starting from a choice of frame over the initial endpoint of $\alpha$.

Comment: It may be that, under this interpretation, the formula may make sense directly in the vector bundle, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't know, I was thinking again, and for $v \in T_xM$, $\phi \in E_x$, we have that $v^{\sf h}_{(x,\phi)} \in T_{(x,\phi)}(E)$, not $E_x$. Applying $P_\alpha$ to $v^{\sf h}_{(x,\phi)}$ still doesn't make sense.

Comment: $P_\alpha$ doesn't apply to $v^{\mathsf{h}}_{(x,\phi)}$, but rather to $\phi$. $(x,\phi)$ is your choice of initial point over $x=\alpha(0)$.

Comment: My point exactly.

Comment: You still need the parallel transport nonetheless, otherwise you don't know over which point of the total space you are computing the curvature tensor and the horizontal lifts.

Comment: In other words, you are computing the curvature tensor and the horizontal lifts over the *final* endpoint of the lift of $\alpha$ to the total space, which is provided precisely by the parallel transport operator applied to $\phi$ (more precisely, to $(x,\phi)$, which is the *initial* endpoint chosen for the lift of $\alpha$).

Comment: I don't know if it'll help, but here is a short note on holonomy and curvature: https://www.math.nyu.edu/~yangd/papers/holonomy.pdf.